# Como posicionar o iframe abaixo de acordo com a posição que eu queira na tela?

Tags: css, iframe, posicionamento

Como posicionar o iframe abaixo de acordo com a posição que eu queira na tela?

```
<div>
            <iframe
                    width="1100"
                    height="500"
                    id="processoControleExterno"
                    src="www.google.com"
                    scrolling="no"
            >
            </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português! Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua pergunta está muito ampla, o padrão da comunidade são perguntas objetivas e que possuam ao menos uma resposta correta, como pode ser visto na [help] no link [ask]. Esta sua pergunta, além de muito ampla pode dar margem a opniões. Faça um passeio pelo [tour] e depois você pode [edit] sua pergunta para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: position:fixed css

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="iframe">
        <iframe
                width="1100"
                height="500"
                id="processoControleExterno"
                src="www.google.com"
                scrolling="no"
        >
        </iframe>
</div>
<style>
    #iframe{
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px; //ou onde você quiser
        left: 10px; //ou onde você quiser
    }
</style>
```